# Fuzzy matching two dataframes and joining on result

Tags: python, fuzzy

Im trying to join two dataframes on string columns which are not identical. I realise this has been asked a lot but I am struggling to find anything relevant to my need. The code I have is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

xls = pd.ExcelFile(filename)

df_1 = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name="Sheet 1")

df_2 = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name="Sheet 2")

df_2['key'] = df_2['Name'].apply(lambda x : [process.extract(x, df_1['Name'], limit=1)][0][0][0])
```

The idea would then be to joing the two datframes based on df_2['key'], However when I run this code it runs but does not return anything. The df sizes are as follows: df_1 (3366, 8) and df_2(1771, 6)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you include all code and data needed to run your program? Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code returns nothing, because it is exactly what it should do.

`df_2['key'] = ...` just appends **'*key'*** columns to **df_2** dataframe.

If you want to merge dataframes, your code should look similar to this:

```
name_list_1 = df_1['Name'].tolist()
name_list_2 = df_2['Name'].tolist()

matches = list(map(lambda x: process.extractOne(
        x, name_list_1, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio)[:2], name_list_2))

df_keys = pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['key', 'score'])
df_2 = pd.merge(df_2, df_keys, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df_2 = df_2[df_2['score'] > 70]
df_3 = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, left_on='Name', right_on='key', how='outer')

print(df_3)
```

I use `extractOne` method, which I guess better suits your situation. It is important to play with `scorer` parameter as it heavily affects matching result.

Comment: Thanks. How can I also return a match percetage to df2 and then apply a minimum match percentage (ie. 70%) on my results or else the results is blank. At present my code is returning some useless values and it will not be beneficial to join on those.

Comment: @GC21 I've modified tha answer: you can use ```score``` value from ratio function.

Answer (score 0):

you can better use `process.extractOne()` instead. you code will look like

```
name_list_1=df_1['Name'].tolist()
name_list_2=df_2['Name'].tolist()
key = map(lambda x : process.extractOne(x,name_list_1)[0],name_list_2)
df_1['key']=key
```

then you can make the join on the `key` column.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am running that code now and will let you know the result. Is there a parameter of process.extractOne() that can adjust the minimum match accuracy?

Comment: Yes, you can use `score_cutoff` parameter to custom define the minimum score for match.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm quite new to python but is there anyway I can optimise the code above as it is taking far too long to run. I have already taken unique values only for name_list.

Comment: i just edited the code. try this one and let know if it is quick.

Comment: Thanks. It was a similar speed. When ive tried to use `score_cutoff` i get this error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Again thanks for all the help.

Comment: can you share the code with me ? Also I have answered your main question then please mark this as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203014/discussion-between-jigyasu-nayyar-and-gc21).